# How to fix fatal PHP error on Wordpress login page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying load my websites Wordpress page but get the error

```
Warning: require(__DIR__/wp-load.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/39/4124639/html/wp-login.php on line 12

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/39/4124639/html/wp-login.php on line 12
```

Inside the `wp-login.php` file on line 12 is: `require __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';`

I confirmed the file `wp-load.php` is there. Can someone help?

I haven't changed my `wp-blog-header.php` file it is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( ! isset( $wp_did_header ) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    // Load the WordPress library.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';

    // Set up the WordPress query.
    wp();

    // Load the theme template.
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php';

}
```

The `wp-load.php` file is (I haven't messed around with it either):

```
<?php
/**
 * Bootstrap file for setting the ABSPATH constant
 * and loading the wp-config.php file. The wp-config.php
 * file will then load the wp-settings.php file, which
 * will then set up the WordPress environment.
 *
 * If the wp-config.php file is not found then an error
 * will be displayed asking the visitor to set up the
 * wp-config.php file.
 *
 * Will also search for wp-config.php in WordPress' parent
 * directory to allow the WordPress directory to remain
 * untouched.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/** Define ABSPATH as this file's directory */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );

/*
 * If wp-config.php exists in the WordPress root, or if it exists in the root and wp-settings.php
 * doesn't, load wp-config.php. The secondary check for wp-settings.php has the added benefit
 * of avoiding cases where the current directory is a nested installation, e.g. / is WordPress(a)
 * and /blog/ is WordPress(b).
 *
 * If neither set of conditions is true, initiate loading the setup process.
 */
if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' ) ) {

    /** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php';

} elseif ( @file_exists( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' ) && ! @file_exists( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-settings.php' ) ) {

    /** The config file resides one level above ABSPATH but is not part of another installation */
    require_once dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php';

} else {

    // A config file doesn't exist.

    define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php';

    // Standardize $_SERVER variables across setups.
    wp_fix_server_vars();

    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php';

    $path = wp_guess_url() . '/wp-admin/setup-config.php';

    /*
     * We're going to redirect to setup-config.php. While this shouldn't result
     * in an infinite loop, that's a silly thing to assume, don't you think? If
     * we're traveling in circles, our last-ditch effort is "Need more help?"
     */
    if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'setup-config' ) ) {
        header( 'Location: ' . $path );
        exit;
    }

    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content' );
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php';

    wp_check_php_mysql_versions();
    wp_load_translations_early();

    // Die with an error message
    $die = sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: wp-config.php */
        __( "There doesn't seem to be a %s file. I need this before we can get started." ),
        '<code>wp-config.php</code>'
    ) . '</p>';
    $die .= '<p>' . sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: Documentation URL. */
        __( "Need more help? <a href='%s'>We got it</a>." ),
        __( 'https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/' )
    ) . '</p>';
    $die .= '<p>' . sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: wp-config.php */
        __( "You can create a %s file through a web interface, but this doesn't work for all server setups. The safest way is to manually create the file." ),
        '<code>wp-config.php</code>'
    ) . '</p>';
    $die .= '<p><a href="' . $path . '" class="button button-large">' . __( 'Create a Configuration File' ) . '</a>';

    wp_die( $die, __( 'WordPress &rsaquo; Error' ) );
}
```

Comment: first of all don't post your login page url to public, second can you post your wp-blog-header.php file . you should modify your login page url !! you don't wanna be hacked .

Comment: What about the contents of your wp-load.php file? Also, what are its permissions like?

Comment: @cabrerahector added contents of wp-load.php above

Comment: post your index.php !

Comment: what is your php version ??

Comment: @AlaaKaddour Posting the index too, now. How can I tell the PHP version? Sorry I'm not experienced in coding, I just did the Wordpress install a long time ago and managed it from there. I never touched any of the default files

Comment: make a php file and put this inside : <?php  phpinfo();

Comment: open it and you will see the php version , what is your hosting provider ??

Comment: The wp-load.php file looks good, doesn't seem any different from what you get when installing WP. Are you sure this file is readable by your server?

Comment: @cabrerahector how can I check that? i've not made any server changes ...

Comment: @AlaaKaddour hosting provider is godaddy